# Binary Search Tree can't delete the root

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Everything is working fine in this function, but the problem is that I can't delete the root, I couldn't figure out what's the bug here.I've traced the "else part" it works fine until the return, it returns the old value I don't know why. Plz Help!

```
node *removeNode(node *Root, int key) {

node *tmp = new node;

if(key > Root->value)
    Root->right = removeNode(Root->right,key);

else if(key < Root->value)
    Root->left = removeNode(Root->left, key);

else if(Root->left != NULL && Root->right != NULL) {
    node *minNode = findNode(Root->right);

    Root->value = minNode->value;

    Root->right = removeNode(Root->right,Root->value);
}

else {
    tmp = Root;

    if(Root->left == NULL)
        Root = Root->right;
    else if(Root->right == NULL)
        Root = Root->left;

    delete tmp;
}

return Root;

}
```

Comment: First thing i can say is :  What if right and left are NULL?

Comment: It gets into the else, then it takes any of the conditions, no?

Comment: Yes, it is just ambigous (Root equals Root->right before returning).

I don't see any error in your code. What did you print during your debug session?

Comment: If I only insert " 40 ", then try to remove it, it won't get removed

Comment: Make new Node for tmp is useless because you will lose the pointer of the new allocated node at line [tmp = Root]

Comment: Can i have all of your code plz?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Vm4wTTr3 Here you go man. And regarding the tmp yes I know, I am too lazy to remove it :P

Comment: You give two time "40" for the test?

Comment: Change removeNode(Root, key); by Root = removeNode(Root, key);

Comment: Cool i'll explain it in comment

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
removeNode(Root, key);
```

To

```
Root = removeNode(Root, key);
```

Root wasn't modify by removeNode because you pass a copy of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using this style, where the result is the new tree, never forget to update the root:

```
Root = removeNode(Root, key);
```

Futhermore an empty tree must be tested for (Root == NULL)

```
node *removeNode(node *Root, int key) {

    if(Root == NULL) // Or if(!Root) return Root;
        return NULL;

    if(key > Root->value)
        Root->right = removeNode(Root->right,key);
    else if(key < Root->value)
        Root->left = removeNode(Root->left, key);

    else if(Root->left != NULL && Root->right != NULL) {
        node *minNode = findNode(Root->right); // Left most leaf
        Root->value = minNode->value;
        Root->right = removeNode(Root->right,Root->value);
    }

    else {
        node *found = Rppt;
        if(Root->left == NULL)
            Root = Root->right;
        else if(Root->right == NULL)
            Root = Root->left;
        delete found;
    }

    return Root;
}
```

---

***Alternative style: using variable aliases***

```
removeNode(&Root, key);

void removeNode(node **ptr_var, int key) {
    node *ptr = *ptr_var;
    if (!ptr)
        return;

    if (key > ptr->value)
        removeNode(&ptr->right,key);
    else if(key < ptr->value)
        removeNode(&ptr->left, key);

    else if(ptr->left && ptr->right) {
        node **minNode = &ptr->right;
        while (*minNode) {
            minNode = &(*minNode)->left;
        }
        ptr->value = (*minNode)->value;
        delete *minNode;
        *minNode = NULL;
    }
    else {
        if(! ptr->left)
            *ptr_var = ptr->right;
        else if(!ptr->right)
            *ptr_var = ptr->left;
        delete ptr;
    }
}
```